# how catch exception when missing font file?

Tags: java, itext

how catch exception when missing font file?

my code are following

```
public static final String FONT_RU = "arialuni.ttf";
public static final String FONT_CH = "hxb-meixinti.ttf";
```

BaseFont bf_ru = BaseFont.createFont(FONT_RU, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

how catch exception when font file (for example hxb-meixinti.ttf) is missing?

Answer (score 0):

The createFont method can throw two exceptions:

DocumentException -> thrown when the font is invalid

IOException -> thrown when the font cannot be read

```
try {
BaseFont bf_ru =BaseFont.createFont(FONT_RU,BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
}
catch (DocumentException e) {
//Font not found/invalid
}
```